# Find $x$ and $y$ in $2^{x-y} + 1 = 2^x,$ where $x,y$ are integers

Tags: factoring, exponentiation

I have no idea what to do now.

Is there any way to find the integers $x$ and $y$ by factoring?

Thank you.

Comment: are $x$ and $y$ integers?

Comment: @hhsaffar Yes, sorry for miss that!

Comment: $2^{x-y}$ and $2^x$ must be one odd and the other even since they differ in 1. There is only one odd power of 2 and is the lesser (integer) power of 2. Since no other pair of powers of 2 differ in 1, then $x-y=0$ and $x=y=1$

Comment: @Kevin: One cannot conclude that $2^k$ is necessarily an integer just because $k$ is an integer. Nor is it (necessarily) immediately clear why no other powers of $2$ (aside from $0$ and $1$) can differ by $1.$ This is the same mistake that the first three answers made initially.

Comment: You are right. I think I am too used to those. For completeness I'll add to my previous reasoning: if $k$ is a negative integer then $0<2^k<1$ and therefore they can't differ in 1 between them. Then there are $2^0=1$ and $2^1=2$ which differ in 1 between them and can't differ 1 with the negative power. Finally for greater powers the difference keep increasing and is always larger than 1 between consecutive powers, and even more so between non-consecutive powers. I was implying that for the reasons I listed in this comment, the powers must be integer since they differ in one

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dividing by $2^x$ gives
$$
2^{-x}+2^{-y}=1
$$
Since $2^{x}\gt0$ for any $x$, we must have both $2^{-x}\lt1$ and $2^{-y}\lt1$; that is, $x\gt0$ and $y\gt0$. Since $x$ and $y$ are integers, the biggest that $2^{-x}$ or $2^{-y}$ can be is $\frac12$ and since their sum is $1$, they must both be $\frac12$.  That means $x=y=1$.

Comment: Verrry nice. +1 on this one too...

Comment: Brilliant! This was my approach too. (Big +1)

Comment: @robjohn : it's not possible to be sure if $2^{-x}<1$ or $2^{-y}<1$, because if $x$ and $y$ are negative integeers, than $2^{-x}>1$

Comment: @Voyager: As I said: $2^x\gt0$ for all $x$ and $2^{-x}+2^{-y}=1$. Thus, both $2^{-x}$ and $2^{-y}$ must be less than $1$. If $2^{-x}\ge1$, then $2^{-y}\le0$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 18):

As an alternative (using factoring), note that $2^{x-y}=\frac{2^x}{2^y},$ so multiplying both sides by the non-zero number $2^y$ yields the equivalent equation $$2^x+2^y=2^x2^y,$$ which in turn yields $$0=2^x2^y-2^x-2^y\\0=2^x(2^y-1)-2^y\\0=2^x(2^y-1)-2^y+1-1\\0=2^x(2^y-1)-(2^y-1)-1\\0=(2^x-1)(2^y-1)-1\\1=(2^x-1)(2^y-1)$$

Note that we cannot have $x=0$ or $y=0$. (Why?) Also $x$ and $y$ must have the same sign, for if not, then $(2^x-1)(2^y-1)$ is negative. If $x,y$ are negative, then $(2^x-1)(2^y-1)$ is positive, but less than $1,$ so we must have $x,y$ positive.

Now, for any positive integers $x,y,$ we have $x,y\ge 1$ (since $x,y$ integers), so $2^x,2^y\ge 2,$ so $2^x-1,2^y-1\ge 1,$ and so $(2^x-1)(2^y-1)\ge 1.$ Equality holds in the last case precisely when it holds in the first case--that is, precisely when $x,y=1.$

Comment: Nice. +1 from me.

Comment: Nice complete argument +1

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** If either of $x$ or $x-y$ is negative, multiplying by $2^z$ where $-z$ is the 
whichever of $x$ and $x-y$ is closer to $- \infty$, we get and equation of the type

$$2^a \pm 1 =2^b \,.$$

Then, as $a \geq 0, b\geq 0$ one of $2^{a}$ or $2^{b}$ has to be odd.

Comment: The numbers $2^{x-y}$ and $2^x$ might not be integers (as 6 voters do not realize).

Comment: @did Missed that, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If they are integers, Which powers of two are 1 apart?

$2^x>1$ so $x > 0$

if $x<y$ then $2^{x-y}\leq\frac{1}{2}$ so $1<2^x \leq \frac32$ and this is impossible.

So $x \geq y$ and $2^{x-y}$ and $2^x$ are integer powers of $2$ and one apart.

So $x-y=0$ and $x=1$, therefore $y=1$.

Comment: The numbers $2^{x-y}$ and $2^x$ might not be integers.

Comment: @Did yes, but in that case, can they be 1 apart?

Comment: No they cannot. But this is what the exercise asks to prove...

Comment: @Did I updated my answer, it was supposed to be a hint and I tried to convey what I think is the core idea in my reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What powers of two are odd? There is only one.

This should tell you what $x - y$ is and from that you can work out what $x$ and $y$ are.

We know that both $x$ and $y$ are integers and $2^x \gt 1$ so $2^x$ must be an integer because the only integer powers of 2 that are not integers are less than 1 so $2^{x-y}$ must also be an integer.

Comment: The numbers $2^{x-y}$ and $2^x$ might not be integers.

Comment: If you check the first comment on the question $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but integer powers of integers need not be integers.

Comment: @CameronBuie they are I've edited my answer to explain why.

Comment: integer $\ne$ positive integer.

Comment: @Did all integer powers of 2 are positive including negative powers (16, 8, 4, 2, 1, $\frac{1}{2}$) etc. and since $2^x$ is a positive integer $2^{x-y}$ is too.

Comment: Listen: a correct proof can be worked out (there is even one on the page), but your post when I commented it was no such proof. No big deal, move on.

Comment: My answer is a hint not a rigorous proof; $x = y = 1$ thus $2^{1-1}+1 = 2^0 + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2 = 2^1$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply with 2^y on both the sides of the equation.

You will get the equation as :-

2^x + 2^y = 2^x * 2^y

Hence on factoring you will get the equation as

(2^x - 1) (2^y - 1) = 1

I think that should help !